# vue-property-decorator: How to modify the parameters of @Emit

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When I saw `@Emit`, I saw the example on GitHub.

```
import { Vue, Component, Emit } from 'vue-property-decorator'
   @Component
   export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
      count = 0
      @Emit()
      addToCount(n: number) {
         this.count += n
      }
   }
```

is equivalent to

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToCount(n) {
      this.count += n
      this.$emit('add-to-count', n)
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

I want to know how to modify this parameter `n`.
I use return statement but it doesn't work.

```
@Emit()
  startChange(num:any){
}
```

The type of the `num` parameter is `Date`.
I want to transform it into `timestamp` and pass it on to the parent component.
How do you do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do something like this:

```
@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
    date: Date

    get timestamp() {
        if (this.date) {
            return this.date.getTime();
        }
    }

    startChange(date: Date) {
        this.date = date
    }

    @Watch('timestamp')
    @Emit('timestampChange')
    onTimestampChanged(timestamp: number) {
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
    timestamp: number

    startChangeByDate(date: Date) {
        this.startChangeByTimestamp(date.getTime())
    }

    @Emit('timestampChange')
    startChangeByTimestamp(timestamp: number) {
        this.timestamp= timestamp
    }
}
```